# How to get a score between 0 and 1 for each class for a CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, softmax

I am currently training a network (CNN implemented with Tensorflow) to classify over 3 classes, the thing is that I end up with score like :

```
[ -20145.36, 150069, 578456.3 ].
```

I would like to have a score between 0 and 1 (some kind of probability).

At first, I thought about using sigmoid function but then I found this discussion where it is not even mentioned :

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-normalize-numeric-scores-to-a-0-1-range-for-comparing-different-machine-learning-techniques

What do you advise me to do to have a score between 0 and 1 for each class ?

Thank you

Comment: tf.nn.softmax() will transform the network output into a valid probability distribution, i.e. all probabilities are between 0 and 1 and they sum up to 1. See here for the TensorFlow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax and here for an explanation: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a final layer, you always use softmax to get n-class classification scores. So, you've quite some options as mentioned in [tensorflow classification docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Classification).

The simplest one is to use [tf.nn.softmax()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax)

```
softmax = exp(logits) / reduce_sum(exp(logits), dim)
```

Example:

```
In [63]: ar = np.array([ -20145.36, 150069, 578456.3 ])

In [64]: scores = tf.nn.softmax(ar)

In [65]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [66]: scores.eval()
Out[66]: array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])
```